# Cookie/Authorization not Carrying over From POST to GET

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, forms-authentication

I've started using Postman to test out my requests and I am now able to authenticate and get the data I'm looking for. When I try to do the same thing in C#, I'm not having as much luck. I've come to understand that the Authorization Header "X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg" will only exist if authorization is still needed or if it failed. Since it now disappears after I attempt authentication with the "_formPost", I am quite certain that it is succeeding. When I do the "request", however, I again get the header with authrequired. So it's not carrying over. I imagine I need to do something more with cookies. What do I need to do?

Update: Apparently the problem was reusing my HttpWebRequest "request". Why can't I reuse it? Why must I make a fresh copy?

```cs
// All the real strings are trustworthy as compared with Postman which works.
string basicCredentials = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(un + ":" + pw));
string formCredentials = "j_username=" + un + "&j_password=" + pw;
string host = "https://my.host.com/ccm/";
string itemUrl = host + "oslc/contexts/_mYsp3ci4lK3y/workitems?stuff"

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(item);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", basicCredentials);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // Do I need anything more here?
request.Headers.Add("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");
request.Accept = "application/rdf+xml";
request.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string AuthHeader = response.Headers["X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg"];

if (AuthHeader.Equals("authrequired")) // Always does
{
    // Now to authenticate with form authentication
    HttpWebRequest _formPost = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "j_security_check"); // Confirmed with Postman
    _formPost.Method = "POST";
    _formPost.Headers.Add("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");
    _formPost.UserAgent = "PostmanHadOneSoIPopulatedThis"; // No clue if necessary
    _formPost.Accept = "text/xml";
    _formPost.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // Setting the cookie container to the request's container hoping
    // it would carry over the authorization. Does this get populated on success?
    _formPost.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;

    // Oddly enough, I must have basic authorization credentials in order to post my form credentials.
    // Otherwise, without this, it continues to say "authrequired" in the header
    _formPost.Headers.Add("Authorization", basicCredentials); 

    // This must be all good. If/When I mess it up, I get the header "authfailed".
    Byte[] _outBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formCredentials);
    _formPost.ContentLength = _outBuffer.Length;
    Stream _str = _formPost.GetRequestStream();
    _str.Write(_outBuffer, 0, _outBuffer.Length);
    _str.Close();

    HttpWebResponse _formResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_formPost.GetResponse();
    string _rtcAuthHeader = _formResponse.Headers["X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg"];

    // Always null now which means it passed authentication
    if (_rtcAuthHeader == null)
    {
        // Trying the request again
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Updating header to check authorization
        _rtcAuthHeader = response.Headers["X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg"];

        // _rtcAuthHeader always == authrequired
        // Did not retain authorization.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it didn't like that I was reusing "Request". I had to create a "NewRequest" with all the same data and try again. No clue why. If you know, feel free to share, but this solved my problem.